# xcodebuild fails due to use of UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll

Tags: xcode, ios6, xcodebuild

This is weird. I never tried xcodebuild earlier (all has been building from xcode).
My project builds perfectly fine from xcode but when i try to build it from terminal it gives me a build error saying "Use of undeclared identifier UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll".

Now AFAIK since I am supplying latest sdk (iphoneos5.1) compiler should recognize the identifier but somehow it doesn't.

Here is the command I am trying..

```
xcodebuild -project /Users/venkat/v13.2.2/reader.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos5.1 DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym GCC_VERSION=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.2_0 COPY_PHASE_STRIP=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGIN_SYMBOLS=YES GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT=YES GCC_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=FULL GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=0
```

I have intentionally chose to keep debug symbols because I need to send this for security testing.

Any pointers would be hugely appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

*UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll* is available in 6.0, not 5.1.

Comment: true.. but when i do a "xcodebuild -showsdks" it shows me iphoneos5.1 as the latest one. I am pretty sure I have iOS 6 sdk installed because I have xcode 4.5 and I am able to build this project directly from there.

Comment: Do you have multiple XCodes side by side? Since with the new XCode everything is bundled in the Xcode.app maybe the wrong _xcodebuild_ is referred in your PATH?

Comment: That's a great catch ! Once i removed older version i could actually see iphoneos6.0... however, although this resolves the error about UIInterfaceOrinentationMaskAll, the build still fails saying "Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.2_0' selected for architecture 'armv7'" I googled a lot but couldn't find anything !

Comment: You need to run "xcode-select -print-path" to see what xcodebuild is pointing at, and very likely change it to use your current Xcode with "xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" unless you have put XCode somewhere different.